# How can I distinguish between different two Interface Builder Scenes sharing same Interface Controller?

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I am developing an Apple Watch Application that has 3 screens with same layout but different values of data and the screens would change on swiping. For this, I have copied the same Interface Builder Scene and linked them by segue (I know this isn't the best approach and I am open for suggestions). Now, I linked them all to the same InterfaceController and want to know which Interface Builder Scene is currently active so that I can set the values of data fields accordingly. Is there a way to access any property of Interface Builder Scene from InterfaceController that can tell which one is selected?

Comment: Why do you want to use the same controllers? What does "the same" mean? The same instance or the same class?

Comment: Same class. Each Interface Builder Scene will get its own instance. But is there any property which can tell me which screen I am on so that I can set the data values accordingly.

Comment: I want the same controller so that I dont have to rewrite all the code to customize the fields. I can simply set the data value according to the screen I am on.

Comment: If you have different instances, simply parametrize the destination instance in `-prepareForSegue:sender:` by passing an identifier (or data or whatever).

Comment: I added the pages by selecting 'next page' from storyboard. Currently I tried to handle it using contextForSegueWithIdentifier:segueIdentifier but its not being called when switching. For this, I would need to handle the page change from code, right?

Comment: Why can't you enter an identifier in Interface Builder?

Comment: I have added it. How can I access it in Interface Controller?